# Writing a formula for excel for labeling sections of time based on a numerical count of # of periods of time

Tags: excel

I didn't have enough space in the title to properly explain the problem

So I have two excel sheets (A and B)

In sheet A, the cycle column is filled out starting from 1 and counting up whenever a Feeding/Drinking appears in the Cycle_type column. The cycles are not always filled out every other row. These are completed excel sheets that sheet B is based off of.

Here's a picture:https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyYGG.png

So for sheet B, similar things, but the cycles are empty:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y01ZT.png

So for the cycle column in sheet B, each of cells have to be filled out based on the time of both sheets A and B.

Per sheet A, cycle 1 corresponds with 41.51. Therefore, in sheet B, anything below 41.51 is filled out with 0 in the cycle column. The next cell in the cycle column for sheet A is 71.07. Anything between 41.51 and 71.07 is filled out with 1 in sheet B.

Back in sheet A, cycle 2 corresponds with 138.14, so anything between 71.07 and 138.14 is filled out with 1.5, and etc etc

So in short, i was wondering if there was a way to write a formula for this somehow, and I just have no clue how to do this.

Comment: Here's what the completed column B would look like: http://imgur.com/a/V588x

Comment: I think you can use [`VlookUp()` with a range](http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/how-to-use-vlookups-range-lookup-feature/).  What have you tried?